# Where clause not working. Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, where-clause

I'm trying to count result from my query which is using  multiple where query. But it doesn't seem to be working.
My syntax is:

```
$partialpaidquery=['month' => $maina];

$partialpaid=Bill::where($partialpaidquery)->where('paid','!=',0)->where('fee_status','<','amount')->count();
```

where clause upto `where('paid','!=',0)` seems to work but the third one is not working. What is the problem here? It actually should have returned 1. But it is returning 0.

Comment: Can you print the query like `dd(DB::getQueryLog());` ?

Comment: No I have no idea. I tried but it is returning empty array [].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use your third where as

```
->whereRaw('fee_status < amount')
```

**because the way you are using it , the amount column is being interpreted as string not column.**

Answer (score 1):

Seems you are using wrong query : 
 You are comparing `<` string `'amount'` instead of use variable `$amount`

like below:

```
$partialpaidquery=['month' => $maina];

$partialpaid=Bill::where($partialpaidquery)->where('paid','!=',0)->where('fee_status','<',$amount)->count();
```

Comment: actually amount is one of the column of my table. I'm trying to compare two columns of single table.

Comment: you are comparing the values of two columns in the same row so you should run `whereRaw` `$partialpaid=Bill::where($partialpaidquery)->where('paid','!=',0)->whereRaw('fee_status < amount')->count();
`